# handle csv import with larga array through a three step process

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax, json

i need some help with a project of mine. It is about a dvd database. In the moment i am planning to implement a csv data function to import dvds with all information from a file. 
I will do this in three steps.

Step 1
- show data i want to import, building array
- import data, building session arrays

Step 2
- edit informations

Step 3
- showing result before update
- update data

so far it works but i have a problem with large files. the csv data has 20 columns (title, genre, plot etc.) and for each line in the csv there are some arrays i create to use it in the next steps.

When i have more about 500 lines the browser often collapse while importing. I get no response.

Anyway now i trying to do this as an ajax call process. The advantage is, that i can define how many procedures the system handle each call and the user can see that the system is still working, like an statusbar when down/uploading a file.

In the moment i try to find some usefull example illustrating how i can do this, but i could not find something useful till now.

Maybe you have some tipps or an example how this could work, saying processing 20 lines each call, building the array.

After i would like to use the same function to build the session arrays using in the next step and so on.

Some information:

i use fgetcsv() to read the rows from the file. i go through the rows and each column i have different querys like is the item id unique, the title exist, description exist etc.
So if one of these data is not entered i get an error which row and column the error occures.

I´d appreciate any help from you

Comment: I suggest you give more information, such as the code you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use 'LOAD DATA INFILE' syntax. ive used it on files upwards of 500mb with 3mil rows and it takes seconds, not minutes.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: I read about this but in this case i must change the complete code which is very much work, so i hop that i can continue working with fgetcsv. If not hm i will not hope so.

Answer (score 1):

While this is not the direct answer you were looking for

500 lines shouldnt take too long to process, so.. heres another thought for you.

Create a temporary table with the right structure of fields
you can then extract from it using select statements the various unique entries for the plot, genre etc rather than making a bunch of arrays along the way
mysql import would be very fast of your data

You can then edit it as required, and finally insert into your final table the data you have from your temporary but now validated table.

In terms of doing it with ajax, you would have to do a repeating timed event to refresh the status, the problem is rather than 20 lines, it would need to be a specific time period, as your browser has no way to know, assuming the csv is uploaded and you can process it in 20 line chunks.

If you enter the csv in a big big textbox, you could work on by taking the first 20 lines, passing it the remainder to the next page etc, would strike me as  potential mess.

So, while I know ive not answered your question directly, I hope I gave you food for thought as to alternative and possibly more practical alternatives

Comment: Yes i also thought to use temporally table for this instead of building the arrays. But i need the data in the next step so then i must do a query and build the new array anyway. For the ajax call i thought to reopen the file each time i call the script passing the start and end of the import. But how can i do this with fgetcsv?

Comment: True but a "select distinct genre" takes a lot less time :)

Comment: I second this approach (with intermediate tables). In the UI you could add options to search, browser, cleanup and lookup values against other tables. The actions would execute against the intermediate table. Once the user is finished, you can do what ever you need with the data. Either insert it directly into a target table (`insert into t(...) select .. from intermediate table`) or just returning the the data as an array.